# Inserting values in the form of a table using div tags and DOM manipulation (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an array which contains employee details like name,id etc which are entered by user in the input form. I want to print these details in the form of table using div alone. kindly tell me the html part and javascript part.
I want to create elements in javascript and print the inputs. The table contains 5 columns and rows gets added as the user enter his input

Comment: Share the relevant code.

Comment: Did you try to write at least 1 line of code so far?

Comment: the question here is just a part of my application , cant post my entire code here!!

Comment: You should never post your entire code unless all of it is relevant. Since "the question here is just a part of my application" post that part. Read about how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to add rows to a table using javascript

```
// Find a <table> element with id="myTable":
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
var row = table.insertRow(0);

// Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

// Add some text to the new cells:
cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
```

Comment: thanks but my prob is, i have a wrapper div in my HTML and i want to create elements in my JavaScript ,add texts ti those elements and display it inside the wrapper div. can you please help me with that?